# Encontrar todos los tickets relacionados con un trabajador. Consulta MySQL complicada

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, join

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de HelpDesk para mi empresa en el que tengo una serie de tablas relacionadas como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: relaciones de tablas]

La tabla principal es `tickets`, donde almaceno los datos básicos del ticket, incluido su autor `id_pers_empleado`.

La tabla más importante es `tickets_asignaciones`, que es donde se indica si el ticket está asignado a un empleado (lo llamaremos agente en esta tabla) `id_agente` o a un equipo `id_equipo`.

Los equipos se definen en la tabla `tickets_equipos` y los agentes que componen cada equipo se indican en la tabla `tickets_equipos_agentes`, que relaciona las tablas `tickets_equipos` y `empleados`.

Lo que necesito es una consulta que me permita obtener todos los tickets...

1. Que tengan como autor a un determinado trabajador X (`WHERE tickets.id_pers_empleado = X`).
2. O que estén asignados directamente a ese trabajador X (`WHERE tickets_asignaciones.id_pers_empleado = X`).
3. O que estén asignados a un equipo al que pertenece dicho trabajador X:

```sql
WHERE 
    tickets.id_pers_empleado IN (
        SELECT 
            tickets_equipos_agentes.id_pers_empleado 
        FROM 
            tickets_equipos_agentes 
        WHERE 
            tickets_asignaciones.id_equipo = tickets_equipos_agentes.id_pers_empleado
   )
 AND
   tickets.id_pers_empleado = X
```

(No estoy seguro si lo anterior es correcto, probablemente no).

Podría hacer esto haciendo múltiples consultas independientes con PHP y bucles `foreach`, pero no quiero sobrecargar el servidor con tantas solicitudes y necesito una consulta que haga todo el trabajo a la vez.

Ya he probado tantos JOINS de diferentes maneras que ahora estoy mareado y estancado. No puedo encontrar la forma correcta de escribir la consulta correctamente. Además, no sé si debería usar subconsultas de alguna manera para lograr lo que estoy intentando.

No creo que el problema esté en la relación o el diseño de las tablas, sino más bien en mi falta de conocimiento sobre este tipo de consultas tan complejas.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea en mente de cómo solventarlo? Gracias.

---

Os pongo un poco el pequeño dataset con el que estoy trabajando.

#### TABLA TICKETS

Aquí el id_pers_empleado es el autor del ticket, es decir, el usuario que ha creado el registro.

```
+-------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+------------------+
| id          | fecha               | titulo                                       | id_tipo | id_pers_empleado |
+=============+=====================+==============================================+=========+==================+
| 00000000001 | 2020/07/26 08:24:40 | Ticket de autoría propia (sin asignación)    | 01      | 00000005         |
+-------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+------------------+
| 00000000002 | 2020/08/08 16:32:43 | Ticket asignado a un solo agente             | 02      | 00000011         |
+-------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+------------------+
| 00000000003 | 2020/08/08 19:19:38 | Ticket asignado a un equipo                  | 02      | 00000012         |
+-------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+------------------+
| 00000000004 | 2020/08/08 19:24:16 | Ticket asignado a varios agentes             | 02      | 00000004         |
+-------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+------------------+
| 00000000005 | 2020/08/08 19:27:21 | Ticket asignado a un equipo y varios agentes | 01      | 00000001         |
+-------------+---------------------+----------------------------------------------+---------+------------------+
```

#### TABLA TICKETS_ASIGNACIONES

En esta tabla `id_pers_empleado` es la persona que asigna el ticket e `id_agente es` la persona a la que se le asigna el ticket. Puede darse el caso de que `id_agente` esté vacío, en cuyo caso es obligatorio que se rellene id_equipo.

Aquí `id_pers_empleado` no puede estar vacío porque se intenta conocer quién es el que ha asignado/escalado el ticket. También cabe la posibilidad de que un ticket en particular no tenga ninguna asignación, bien porque el ticket es nuevo y aún no se ha decidido a quién debe asignarse o bien porque se trata de un ticket informativo y no requiere intervención por parte de ningún agente.

```
+-------------+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| id_ticket   | id_pers_empleado | id_equipo | id_agente |
+=============+==================+===========+===========+
| 00000000002 | 00000011         |           | 00000005  |
+-------------+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 00000000003 | 00000002         | 02        |           |
+-------------+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 00000000004 | 00000003         |           | 00000003  |
+-------------+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 00000000004 | 00000002         |           | 00000002  |
+-------------+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 00000000005 | 00000001         | 04        |           |
+-------------+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 00000000005 | 00000001         |           | 00000001  |
+-------------+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 00000000005 | 00000001         |           | 00000004  |
+-------------+------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

#### TABLA TICKETS_EQUIPOS

Es el puente entre `tickets_asignaciones` y `tickets_equipos_agentes`, y guardará también otros datos como el icono, color, y quién es el líder del equipo, pero no son relevantes así que no los he incluido.

```
+-------------+--------------+
| id          | nombre       |
+=============+==============+
| 00000000001 | Contabilidad |
+-------------+--------------+
| 00000000002 | RRHH         |
+-------------+--------------+
| 00000000003 | Calidad      |
+-------------+--------------+
| 00000000004 | Técnico      |
+-------------+--------------+
```

#### TABLA TICKETS_EQUIPOS_AGENTES

Aquí el `id_pers_empleado` es el trabajador que pertenece a un equipo de la tabla anterior. Un mismo trabajador/agente puede estar en varios equipos a la
vez.

```
+-------------+------------------+
| id_equipo   | id_pers_empleado |
+=============+==================+
| 00000000001 | 00000001         |
+-------------+------------------+
| 00000000001 | 00000098         |
+-------------+------------------+
| 00000000002 | 00000006         |
+-------------+------------------+
| 00000000002 | 00000007         |
+-------------+------------------+
| 00000000002 | 00000008         |
+-------------+------------------+
| 00000000003 | 00000001         |
+-------------+------------------+
| 00000000003 | 00000011         |
+-------------+------------------+
| 00000000003 | 00000098         |
+-------------+------------------+
| 00000000004 | 00000005         |
+-------------+------------------+
| 00000000004 | 00000034         |
+-------------+------------------+
```

---

### Aproximación hasta el momento

La mejor forma que he encontrado hasta ahora para mostrar los resultados que busco es esta:

```sql
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.id_pers_empleado autor,
    t1.titulo,
    t2.id_agente,
    t2.id_equipo,
    t3.nombre nombreEquipo
FROM
    tickets t1
LEFT JOIN
    tickets_asignaciones t2 ON t1.id = t2.id_ticket 
LEFT JOIN
    tickets_equipos t3 ON t2.id_equipo = t3.id
WHERE
    t1.id_pers_empleado = 5
OR
    t2.id_agente = 5
OR
    t1.id_pers_empleado IN (
        SELECT
            id_pers_empleado 
        FROM
            tickets_equipos_agentes t4
            LEFT JOIN tickets_equipos t5 ON t4.id_equipo = t5.id
        WHERE t4.id_equipo = t3.id
    )
GROUP BY t1.id
ORDER BY t1.id
```

El resultset de la operación es este:

```
+-------------+----------+----------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| id_ticket   | autor    | titulo                                       | id_agente | id_equipo | nombreEquipo |
+=============+==========+==============================================+===========+===========+==============+
| 00000000001 | 00000005 | Ticket de autoría propia (sin asignación)    |           |           |              |
+-------------+----------+----------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| 00000000002 | 00000011 | Ticket asignado a un solo agente             | 5         |           |              |
+-------------+----------+----------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| 00000000005 | 00000001 | Ticket asignado a un equipo y varios agentes |           | 4         | Técnico      |
+-------------+----------+----------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+
```

A priori parece que funciona pero no sé si lo estoy haciendo de la mejor manera o hay algo que podría mejorarse de la consulta.

Comment: Debería resolverse con `JOINS`, sin liarte demasiado con sub-consultas. Simplemente ve uniendo cada cada tabla con la(s)  otras tablas relacionadas. Si te estancas muestra lo que tienes hecho y el error o resultado que obtienes.

Comment: Yo creo que puedes lograrlo pero quizá lo mejor sea utilizar 3 consultas con los `JOINS` necesarios y luego utilizar `UNION`, por la estructura de las tablas quizá sea más complicado intentar hacerlo en una sola consulta (?). Comparte un pequeño dataset de ejemplo si te es posible. Saludos.

Comment: no entiendo la diferencia entre agente y personal, por qué en la table tickets_asignaciones hay dos relaciones a empleados? Un empleado puede estar a cargo de uno o varios equipos? un equipo puede estar asignados a varios empleados?

Comment: La diferencia es el rol. En esa tabla `id_pers_empleado` actúa como la persona que ejecuta la acción de asignar el ticket e `id_agente` es la persona a la que se le asigna el ticket. Dentro de la tabla un mismo `id_pers_empleado` puede asignar el ticket X a uno o varios agentes e incluso a uno o varios equipos de agentes (que son los que se encargarán de manejar y resolver el ticket).


Esto es así porque el ticket a priori no tiene a nadie asignado hasta que pasa por una o varias personas que son las encargadas de derivarlo a los agentes o equipos correctos.

Comment: He añadido el dataset, la consulta que llevo hasta el momento y el resultset de esa consulta. Parece que funciona pero no tengo claro que esté bien. ¿Qué me decís?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que tu aproximación es buena, el mayor inconveniente que le veo es a dificultad de darle mantenimiento, pues quizás para ti mismo dentro de unos años, o para otra persona, no sea tan fácil comprender la idea que está detrás de la consulta.

Creo que has expresado muy bien en palabras lo que quieres hacer y mi sugerencia es que hagas, en SQL, lo mismo que describes en palabras, que es la unión de tres consultas distintas, para formar el *universo* de tickets relacionados con un empleado.

En la consulta a continuación agrego un campo ficticio solo para mostrar de dónde viene la relación, quizás no te interese conservarlo a la hora de hacer tu consulta final, pero por ahora, será de utilidad para comprobar que funciona correctamente:

```
select id, 'autor' relacion
  from Tickets
 where id_pers_empleado = 5
union 
select t.id, 'asignado directamente'
  from Tickets t
       inner join tickets_asignaciones ta on ta.id_ticket = t.id
 where ta.id_agente = 5
union
select t.id, 'asignado al equipo'
  from Tickets t
       inner join tickets_asignaciones ta on ta.id_ticket = t.id
       inner join tickets_equipos e on e.id = ta.id_equipo
       inner join tickets_equipos_agentes ea on ea.id_equipo = e.id
 where ea.id_pers_empleado = 5
```

Con tus datos de prueba, para el `id` de empleado `5`, devuelve:

```
id  relacion
1   autor
2   asignado directamente
5   asignado al equipo
```

Si tienes MySQL 8 o superior, puedes convertir esta consulta en un CTE y a partir de allí conseguir cualquier otra información que necesites. En versiones anteriores de MySQL, puedes ir agregando campos a las distintas consultas para mantener la unión en funcionamiento, o convertir la consulta en una tabla derivada, sobre la que puedas hacer joins, por ejemplo para traer todos los datos del Ticket:

```
select Tickets.*
  from Tickets
       inner join (
                  /* propiedad del empleado */
                  select id
                    from Tickets
                   where id_pers_empleado = 5
                  union
                  /* asignados directamente */
                  select t.id
                    from Tickets t
                         inner join tickets_asignaciones ta on ta.id_ticket = t.id
                   where ta.id_agente = 5
                  union
                  /* asignados a un equipo al que pertenece el empleado */
                  select ta.id_ticket
                    from tickets_asignaciones ta
                         inner join tickets_equipos e on e.id = ta.id_equipo
                         inner join tickets_equipos_agentes ea on ea.id_equipo = e.id
                   where ea.id_pers_empleado = 5
        ) TicketsAsociadosEmpleado
        on TicketsAsociadosEmpleado.id = Tickets.id
```

En mi opinión, una consulta como esta, es mucho más fácil de comprender, sobre todo si se agrega algún comentario. A menos que tu sistema esté lidiando con miles o millones de registros, o alta concurrencia, sugiero que no te preocupes por el rendimiento, mientras una quizás termina en 14 milisegundos y la otra en 28, que es el doble, para un humano, ambas vienen siendo lo mismo.

Comment: Esta solución me ha sido mucho más fácil de integrar que la otra respuesta. El único cambio que he hecho es seleccionar todos los campos de la tabla `tickets` (`t.*`) en lugar de solo el id del ticket, lo cual me ha permitido no solo obtener el ID y la relación, sino también los otros campos que tenía el ticket lo cual ya me ahorra otra consulta para obtener dichos campos. Lo marco como respuesta. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Si vas a utilizar sub-consultas yo creo que sería algo así.

```
SELECT * FROM TICKETS 
WHERE ID_PERS_EMPLEADO=X -- QUE EL AUTOR SEA EL EMPLEADO X
OR ID IN 
        (SELECT ID_TICKET FROM TICKETS_ASIGNACIONES WHERE ID_PERS_EMPLEADO = X) -- QUE ESTE ASIGNADO Al EMPLEADO X
OR ID IN    
    (SELECT ID_EQUIPO FROM TICKETS_ASIGNACIONES WHERE ID IN (
            SELECT ID_EQUIPO FROM EQUIPOS_AGENTES WHERE ID_PERS_EMPLEADO = X)) -- QUE ESTE ASIGNADO A UN EQUIPO DEL EMPLEADO X
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda,
un saludo.

Comment: Consultando por el `id_pers_empleado = 5` me devuelve el ticket 1, que sería correcto, y el ticket 4, que está asignado a los empleados 3 y 2, pero no al 5. Pero veo por donde vas. A ver si puedo hacer algo en base a eso.

Comment: Gonzalo, bienvenido a StackOverflow. Aquí utilizamos [markdown](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) para dar formato a preguntas y respuestas. Edité tu respuesta para darle formato al código que publicas, con lo cual mantiene la indentación y  se resalta la sintaxis. Te invito a darle clic en `editar` arriba, para ver como se hace. Un saludo.